# NPM request module - connection or resource exhaustion/starvation?

Tags: node.js, http, network-programming, network-protocols

We have a server at work whereby after about 12 hours it no longer is able to make new connections to any URL.

We are using the NPM

```
request
```

module which is just a convenience wrapper around the native

```
http
```

module TMK.

So I don't currently have that much info, but I do know we make a request to certain URLs at least once per second.

What kinds of settings or events could begin to exhaust the request lib such that no new connections could be made? It seems to be resource exhaustion of some variety.

I am not that good with network I/O so my only guess is that we aren't closing sockets or connections when we need to?

My question is - since we haven't really ruled out even the most likely scenarios, what are the most likely causes of not being able to make a request with the http/request module after a certain number of requests?